# Creating GUI for a simple python script

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have this little script that counts how many words there are in a file and how many times a word repeats. I want to make a gui in wxPython in which i can enter the filename and it will show me the result.

I've been looking at wxPython examples but still haven't got the hang of it. Here's the script

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import re
import operator

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        sys.exit("Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" files...");
line = sys.argv[1:]
num = 0
dic = {}
for i in line:
        dat = open(i, "r").read()
        words = re.findall(r'[a-z]+',dat)
        for word in words:
                if len(word)>3:
                        num=num+1
                        if dic.has_key(word):
                                dic[word]=dic[word]+1
                        else:
                                dic[word]=1
print num

sorted_dic = sorted(dic.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print sorted_dic
```

Comment: What kind of files are you reading? txt or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at wx.FileDialog to get you started. Here's a tutorial that talks about all the standard dialogs, including the file dialog: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/ (scroll down about half-way).

Now you'll probably open the file dialog with some sort of button. So you bind the button to EVT_BUTTON and open the file dialog in the event handler. Something like this:

```
myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openFileDialog)
```

Now in your openFileDialog (event handler) method, you can open the dialog and retrieve the path. At this point, you pass the path to the code you've already written which can be a part of the event handler or you could put it in its own method. Then when you get the result, you would probably want to display it in a wx.StaticText widget or perhaps show it in a wx.MessageBox

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is, what part of the GUI (That isn't shown here) are you having trouble with? Instead of wxPython, check out [tkinter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html). In tkinter, you can use the [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) and get the filepath of the file you want to open and parse, although wxPython has similar funcitonality.

I don't want to write out the code for you, but basically, it'll require:

- Create a frame,
- Create the button that'll be bound to the command that'll launch the tkFileDialog
- Another set of widgets that'll be bound to the command that'll count the words in the file
- Display your results somehow.

Comment: wx.python also have FileDialog

Comment: @DomagojHack Thanks, for sure. I just wanted him to start with an easier GUI since wx is a little trickier to get started with.

Comment: I don't have the gui, i just have the script i showed. I now want to write a gui for this script and i need to learn wx because i have to work on a project that uses wx, so i'm starting with some small scripts i have.